# Rails Migration Add_Index issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to add indexing to my users table for the email column. Typing `rails g migration add_index_to_users_email` generates the migration but the function is empty. The snake casing should be correct, so I'm at a loss as to why the migration is being created but the change function inside is empty.

I've also tried `AddIndexToUsersName` and the same issue arises.

Any direction on what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated. Only thing I can think of is that I'm using Postgres and not MySQL or SQLite, but that wouldn't matter would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, migration generators only support addition and removal of columns, with a specified modifier. For example, if you wished to add a *new* string column `phone` to the `users` table, you could use the command

```
rails generate migration AddPhoneToUsers phone:string
```

Check the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) for column modifiers. You can *try*

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToUsers email:index
```

to add an index to the existing column. However, I am not sure if generators support column modification. You can write the migration yourself, assuming the `email` column already exists on the `users` table:

```ruby
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I also see where I errored in assuming my original rails migration would work. I misread Hartl's explanation on what to do. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Quick question, who is Hartl?

Comment: [Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/), I've really been digging the book. Very in depth giving thorough explanations to everything.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

The correct command is

```
rails g migration AddIndexToUsers email:string:index
```

This will generate:

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

Edit the migration file and delete the `add_column` line, then run the migration.